# I want to make a small sculpture out of plants. Would chicken wire be suitable for sculpting the shape?

Tags: design

I recently watched The Big Flower Fight on Netflix and I want to make a sculpture of a small dog out of plants. I picked a small dog because I expect it won't need much support and no issues falling over, unlike some of the sculptures on that show.

I noticed on the show, many contestants used chicken wire. They cut it and shaped it into what they needed for their particular sculpture.

Would chicken wire be suitable for this job or are there better materials I should be using?

Comment: I don’t know. But I recently watched and enjoyed the big flower show !

Comment: Search "topiary" for information.